# Count of groups of certain groups of documents

Tags: mongodb

Documents in this mongodb has the property `createdAt = Date.now()` which is the epoch time as well as the properties `userid` and `name`.
What is needed is the count of documents for `name='abc'` which are created less or equal to 4 months ago, but counting those documents which were created by the same userId and on the same day as one count.
What is the best way to go about it? aggregate or map or combination or ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below aggregation.

```
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2017, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0)); 
date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 4);

db.collection.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        createdAt: {
            $gte: date,
            $lte: new Date(Date.UTC(2017, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0))
        },
        name: "abc"
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            date: {
                $dayOfMonth: "$createdAt"
            },
            month: {
                $month: "$createdAt"
            },
            year: {
                $year: "$createdAt"
            },
            userid: "$userid"
        },
        count: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: I am getting ISODate is not defined on the server console. I am in Australia, not sure if that makes any difference..

Comment: Updated to use JavaScript date object. See if it helps